# Strange result of elisp while

Tags: elisp

Why does the following code snippet print `nil` instead of the last element?

```
(progn
  (setq lst '(3 5 7))
  (while (not (equal lst (car lst)))
    (setq lst (cdr lst)))
  ;; BODY
  (print lst))
```

*Note:* I need to process the last element differently than the rest of the list.

Comment: `(equal lst (cdr lst))` is only true for the empty list. My poor LISP skills tell me that it should probably be `(equal lst (car lst))`.

Comment: My mistake. with 'car' same result.

Comment: @HristoIliev: `(equal lst (car lst))` is *also* only true for the empty list (and some weird circular lists, but let's ignore those for now...).

Comment: It works: (while (not (= (length lst) 1))

Answer (score 1):

Because the `cdr` of the last element is `nil`, and you are setting the variable to that.

Generally, the `car` of each `cons` is a value (which could be a pointer to another list), and the `cdr` is a pointer to the remainder of the list. So when traversing a list, you usually want to operate on the `car`.

```
(progn
  (setq lst '(3 5 7))
  (while (cdr lst))
    (setq lst (cdr lst)))
  (print (car lst)))
```

Any basic Lisp introduction will have better visualizations than I have, but if you have read one, this should look familiar. The basic building block of a list is a cons cell with a `car` and a `cdr` (the names are apparently holdovers of register names used in the first Lisp implementations).

```
+------+------+
| car  | cdr  |
+------+------+
```

Your list with three elements will have three conses; `(3 . (5 . (7 . nil)))` or graphically

```
+---+---+  +---+---+  +---+---+
| . | o--->| . | o--->| . | o---#
+-v-+---+  +-v-+---+  +-v-+---+
  3          5          7
```

So the `car` of the first cons is (a pointer to) the value 3, and its `cdr` is (a pointer to) the next `cons` in the list.